# Chef bash execute not_if some command returns 1

Tags: ruby, git, bash, maven, chef-infra

I need to checkout code in git repo & do `mvn clean package` only if code in repo dir contains wrong branch. How can I do this with (or without) not_if in chef recipe?

```
bash "checkout_and_compile_if_wrong_version" do
  user "develop"
  group "develop"
  cwd "/var/www/"
  environment 'HOME' => "/home/develop"
  code <<-EOH
            cd /var/www/code_repo/
            git checkout #{node['last_version']}
            git pull
            mvn clean package
  EOH
  not_if { ...condition... }
end
```

Maybe I can use for a condition something like check (in code_repo dir):

```
[ "$(git branch |grep "*" |awk '{print $2}')" == #{node['last_version']} ] && echo 1
```

Thx in advance.

Comment: Have you thought about using `not_if` instead? This probably does the negation you're looking for

Comment: So what's your question then? You just need to figure out the command to use.

Comment: yup, I need to figure out the command to use and in which way it would be correct in `not_if {...}`, if I use mine..

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're asking. Why don't you just try it until you get it working? You're in the best position to solve this!

Comment: I can't get correct syntax for this, as I'm newbie in ruby. All, that I've already tried, berkshelf marked as syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chef has a [git resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_git.html), clearly best adapted to your use case.

I would do something like this (untested code):

```
execute "clean package" do
  cwd "/var/www/code_repo/"
  command "mvn clean package"
  user "develop"
  group "develop"
  action :nothing
end

git "/var/www/code_repo/" do
  repository "you_repo_url"
  revision node['last_version']
  user "develop"
  group "develop"
  action :sync
  notifies :run,"execute[clean package]", :immediately
end
```

This will sync if a new commit is done or if `node['last_version']` change and run `mvn clean` only when there's a change. The `HOME` env var is set by git resource so it does not need to be provided.

---

Edit per comment:

Quoting the `not_if` or `only_if` guard documentation before anything:

> A string is executed as a shell command. If the command returns 0, the
>   guard is applied. If the command returns any other value, then the
>   guard attribute is not applied

recipe code:

```
bash "whatever" do
  command "test"
   only_if %Q{git branch | awk '/^[*] / { exit $2=="#{node['last_version']}"}'}, :cwd => "/var/www/code_repo"

end
```

Tricky part:
The bash would work only if the version is not equal to the `node['last_version']` (guard printing 0 by the equality test within awk)

I simplified the grep/awk/test part in a single awk script working on line starting with `*` (the regex inside the `/ /`) and then telling awk to exit with the result of comparison between the second field (the actual git branch) and the chef attribute version. The `%Q{ code and "quote test indide" }` is a ruby form to allow using quotes without having to escape them.

If the comparison is true, do nothing, if it's false, run the bash script.

I highly advise trying to use chef resources whenever possible and trying to replace bash script code with chef resources as much as possible. (It's easier to maintain and keep idempotent in time)

Comment: thx, m8, I've alredy used git resource long ago, but it gave me some issues, that I can't remember.. But I'll give it a try one more time))

Comment: But, if you know, how to run my command above, I'll be grateful (just for an interest)

Comment: @Blasterdick sorry, missed a point, the cwd attribute, refining my test case and editing in a few.

Comment: @Blasterdick this time it's ok (there was a problem with the regex at first too)

Comment: `git branch | awk '/^[*] / { print $2==#{node['last_version']} }'` will always give 0, it should be `git branch | awk '/^[*] / { print $2 == "#{node['last_version']}" }'`, but it can't be like that with double-quotes.. Any glue?..